# (VSCode Mac) Unable to start debugging, and yes I've googled it, and nothing helped

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've seen posts about this but none directly related to me (for ex. they were not on Mac).

Main.app :

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int val = 500;

int main() 
{ 
    int val = 200; 
    cout << "Value of global x is " << ::val;
    cout << "Value of local x is " << val;
    return 0; 
}
```

Main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int val = 500;

int main() 
{ 
    int val = 200; 
    cout << "Value of global x is " << ::val;
    cout << "Value of local x is " << val;
    return 0; 
}
```

launch.json : https://pastebin.com/UqK9yFWJ

tasks.json : https://pastebin.com/fqMNs3JT

Problem
[image: Problem Error]

Project Files Hierarchy
[image: Project Files Hierarchy]

I'm not really sure where to go from here and I don't really know what else to put in as for info. If you can help me, that would be great.

Comment: Do you attempt to debug the actual *source code?* You should not have a `Main.app` with source code. You should build the source file `Main.cpp` into an executable program that can then be debugged.

Comment: I'm not actually sure how to do that...

Comment: And please ead about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Don't post links to important information. Links can go stale or otherwise become invalid. Questions needs to be self-contained, or the rick becoming worthless baggage. We're not here to help only you right now, but also future people who might have the same problem. Copy-paste text into the question body instead.

Comment: yes, i know. and im not trying to create excuses for doing this but i just moved on from a language in which didnt really need any help with and just started using forums

Comment: im gonna research what you first said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a multitude of ways to setup a simple VSCode on macOS for debugging. The following is one of them, and it should point you in the correct direction.

First, your Main.app is simply wrong. A .app program is traditionally written in Objective C or Swift, and is generally a native Cocoa-based macOS application. You're not doing that. You're essentially just trying to debug a *console* application. A **very** basic setup of that task is below

First the launch.json. This is what tells VSCode what to run

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/YourProgramNameHere",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Next, the tasks.json. This is what tells VSCode how to build your code.

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Project",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "--std=c++14",
                "-o",
                "YourProgramNameHere",
                "main.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And finally, the main source file itself (nothing terribly exciting here):

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}
```

Putting that all together, you run your build either by the default hot key (assuming you haven't changed it, it's shift-cmd-B), or select it from the command palette (shift-cmd-P), then type `Build`, and the default build command should be found. This will execute the build command defined in your tasks.json.

To then debug, switch to the Debug explorer, which, with the provided launch.json above, will have a launch option called `(lldb) Launch`. Running that should run your program, and if you establish break points in the source files before-hand, they should trip.

---

This is just one way to do this. There are others that can get far more complicated, but for building a simple project of a few files and debugging it, this is about as basic as it gets.

Hope it helps.

Comment: omg, finally someone who knows his stuff. thanks a bunch, this works for me

Comment: now i can finally use vscode to practice all types of code :D